# AVEDEV Function equivalent in DAX?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm hoping someone may be able to help, I'm looking to create a DAX measure that replicates the AVEDEV (excel function).  I want to find the AVEDEV of the "Fail Rate 2" measure with an average taken for the previous 180 days.

[image]

Thank you,

D

There doesn't appear to be a DAX equivalent of this Excel function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVEDEV returns the average of the absolute deviations of data points from their mean. In DAX you can calculate AVEDEV of the past 180 days with this measure:

```
AVEDEV 180D = 
VAR prev180 = 
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Date] >= TODAY() -180
            && 'Table'[Date] < TODAY()
    )
VAR mean = 
    AVERAGEX(
        prev180,
        [Value]
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            prev180,
            ABS([Value] - mean)
        ),
        COUNTROWS(prev180)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter, this is excellent thank you! How would the code differ, If I was to add the AVEDEV 180D column to a table visual and have the each date with a new calculated AVEDEV for the previous 180 days?